# how to save a Graph in a file and later call it?

Tags: c++, file, graph, save

I have to read file that represent a circuit. Then convert that circuit to DAG. I've done that using adjacency list.

My question is how to save the DAG into file so that i dont have to read the file again with each program execution?

I mean just read the file once and construct the graph. Then whenever we need that graph we just simply call it or read it.

like we have in MATlAB:

```
% save the constructed graph    
save ('Graph.mat', 'Graph';
% simply just load it
load Graph;
```

My problem is some circuits are really large and take a considerable time to translated to graph. And it would be really frustrating if this circuit to Graph conversion happens with every run. (in C++)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have conflicting requirements... You want to be able to save the graph to a file (in some format), but you should not have to load it back from the file? Or do you mean that you don't want to read the *original* file and recreate the graph? That's very different, and in my opinion not worth it. Is your graph-creating code slow or bad in some way? Why can't you just read the original circuit-description file and recreate the graph when needed?

Comment: Yes i dont want to recreate the graph every time. And the Graph creation is a really  slow process. because i may need the DAG several times in different parts of my project

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is [Serialization and Unserialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization). There are many ways to do this but basically you want to store enough data to be able to reconstruct all your objects and there interrelationships. Where MATLAB and other systems to do this for you, in C++ you'll have to design the system yourself.  Best idea is to chose a known and stable way to represent the data (*eg* JSON), use a library for that, and design the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems i should code a lot to do this, right? i was looking for some library or exiting algorithm for this. I think deal with it as is, because it works but unfortunately time consuming